# How to display error message after counting invalid login attempts in angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular Material sign-in component which shows an error via  when authentication fails, I need to count login attempts for a particular user and if the user enters the wrong password 3 times, display an error message like "Failed: USERID REVOKED" ...but I don't know how to do that being new to Angular.

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Here's what the OKTA example does:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <h2>Log In</h2>
  <mat-error *ngIf="loginInvalid">
    The username and password were not recognised
  </mat-error>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="username" required>
    <mat-error>
      Please provide a valid email address
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
    <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" required>
    <mat-error>
      Please provide a valid password
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

and the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {AccessService} from '../access.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  public loginInvalid = false;
  private formSubmitAttempt = false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private accessService: AccessService) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: ['user', Validators.required],
      password: ['pass', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  }

  async onSubmit(): Promise<void> {
    this.loginInvalid = false;
    this.formSubmitAttempt = false;
    if (this.form.valid) {
      try {
        const username = this.form.get('username')?.value;
        const password = this.form.get('password')?.value;
        await this.accessService.authenticate(username, password);
      } catch (err) {
        this.loginInvalid = true;
      }
    } else {
      this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You honestly want to send the failed attempts via server side so when you post to get authorized to your api/ web service . You will have to create the logic in api/webservice that logs and stores failed attempts. you could store it in distributed cache or a db and have tasks when to archive and ultimately remove those records when you deem it.   Upon a third attempt you could have your auth service from your api/web service return a response that angular could take and then act accordingly such as showing your validation error message or potential reset password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a counter to track # of attempts. When it hits 3 show an alert/or modal from the UI library you are using.

```
invalidedAttemptCounter: number;

ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  this.invalidedAttemptCounter = 0  
}

async onSubmit(): Promise<void> { 
  ...
  ...
  ...

  catch (err) {
    this.loginInvalid = true;
    this.invalidedAttemptCounter++;

    if (this.invalidedAttemptCounter ===3) {
      alert('Failed: USERID REVOKED');

      // or insert the UI library based code here to display a nice modal

    }

  }
}
```

You can also disable/hide the `Login` button after 3 failed attempts.

```
// to hide (preferred)
<button *ngIf="invalidedAttemptCounter < 3" mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>

// to disable
<button [disabled]="invalidedAttemptCounter === 3" mat-raised-button color="primary">Login</button>
```